# SQL Select constants with Union All then Join with IQueryable, EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Using EF 6

Is it possible to generate the following SQL via Linq:

```
 select partition,
    <calculation>,
    ...
 from
 (
   select ...
     from SomeEntity sm
     cross join (
       select 'June' as [partition] 20140601 as [start], 20140630 as [end] union all
       'July', 20140701, 20140731 union all,
       'Sommar', 20140601, 20150828
     ) as cons
     ....
     where sm.SomeProp >= cons.[start] and sm.SomeProp <= cons.[end]
   )
   group by partition
   ....
```

Calling Queryable.SelectMany bails on Unable to use the **cons** which I defined as an Array.AsQueryable() since the object isn't a primitive or enum.  Any way to get around bending Enumerable with Queryable so that the temporary **cons** table can be made with the *select ... union all* construct?  Maybe extend the provider?

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches. One is to turn your problem on it's head and do a query like this:

Approach 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeEntity
WHERE sm.SomeProp >= [start1] and sm.SomeProp <= [end1]
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM SomeEntity
WHERE sm.SomeProp >= [start2] and sm.SomeProp <= [end2]
...
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM SomeEntity
WHERE sm.SomeProp >= [startx] and sm.SomeProp <= [endx]
```

Approach 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeEntity
WHERE 1=0 /* Always false */
OR (sm.SomeProp >= [start1] and sm.SomeProp <= [end1])
OR (sm.SomeProp >= [start2] and sm.SomeProp <= [end2])
..
OR (sm.SomeProp >= [startx] and sm.SomeProp <= [endx])
```

Approach 1 in LINQ would look like this:

```
// Wrap in if(!array.Any()) if you want to handle the case where array is empty
var temp1=array.First(); // will throw exception if array is empty
var query=_db.SomeEntity.Where(s=>s.SomeProp>=temp1.start && s.SomeProp<=temp1.end));
foreach(var pair in array.Skip(1))
{
  var temp=pair;
  query=query.Union(
    _db.SomeEntity.Where(s=>s.SomeProp>=temp.start && s.SomeProp<=temp.end));
}
```

Approach 2 in LINQ would likely use a predicate builder like so:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<SomeEntity>();
foreach (var pair in array)
{
  var temp=pair;
  predicate = predicate.Or(s=>s=>s.SomeProp>=temp.start && s.SomeProp<=temp.end));
}
var result=_db.SomeEntity.Where(predicate);
```

Comment: Approach 1 is solid SQL (slightly faster despite a little more CPU overhead).  Problem is that I generate the Expression tree off a JSON Query grammar.  The Cross Join approach is fairly easy to explicitly translate into a Tree while the Union approach is harder to do declarative.

Comment: With a larger number of partitions (i.e. Unions in Robert's approach) the CPU usage and scans gets heavy.  Worried about scaling.  Approach 2 can't handle overlapping partitions.  The Cross Join is pretty effective.  There has to be a way to adjust the Provider or EF to generate a temporary table off an Enumerable.

Comment: If it is going to be that large, perhaps you could write your parameters into a table then run your query against it using conventional joins?  Or alternatively, you can serialize the array into xml and do a join against a SQL Server UDF that takes xml as input and return a table and cross join on that?

Comment: I believe TDS has a limit of 2100 parameters per call, so if you are worried about scaling beyond 700ish partitions (3 fields per partition), then you will need to find a way to reduce the number of parameters sent.  You could do it via Xml, TVP, or splitting a very large string, but you'll need to use one of them.

Comment: I do not believe (I could be wrong) EF/LINQ supports TVPs, so this article may help you: http://blog.mikecouturier.com/2010/01/sql-2008-tvp-table-valued-parameters.html which uses ADO.NET to fill a table based on a TVP.  I suspect you could possibly extend the query provider to detect TVPs and use somethign like that to fill a temporary table, then change the query to refer to that instead.  Or possibly look at how ADO.NET handles SqlDbType.Structured and do something similar.